# What does >>= mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I found this in the dojo.js library:

```
13444: color >>= bits;
```

Context:

```
ArrayUtil.forEach(["b", "g", "r"], function(x){
  var c = color & mask;
  color >>= bits;
  t[x] = bits == 4 ? 17 * c : c;
});
```

I can't find any reference to it anywhere else.  It's not in the O'Reilly JavaScript pocket reference or the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax).

I know what it means in functional programming, but I'm pretty sure JavaScript doesn't support monads!

Comment: MDN is quite a good resource for documentation. See the page on [Assignment Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the same a `color = color >> bits` - similar to operators like +=, -=, *= ...

**EDIT**

The `>>` (in the integer context) shifts bits to the right, i.e. dividing by 2 but keeping the sign bit in the same place

Comment: Ok. Is it standard syntax? As I said, I can't find reference to it anywhere else.

Comment: @NickBrunt, http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf See sections 7.7 and 11.7

Comment: No, I know what >> does, I was only confused by the = part as I didn't know JavaScript supported the shorthand assignment operator for shifts.

Answer (score 2):

It is *Right Shift* operator. For example, the `a >> b` operator is actually same as **a/2<sup>b</sup>**.

In your case, it is equal to: `color = color >> bits` where `color >> bits` stands for **color/2<sup>bits</sup>**

As you can see, it divides first operand with `2` raised power of second operand eg **2<sup>bits</sup>**; whatever is the value of `bits` there.

---

You can read more about it at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

Answer (score 1):

```
x >>= y
```

Is the same as

```
x = x >> y
```

Heres the reference that you need:
[Assignment Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) doc from mozilla

And also "[Rare Javascript Operators](http://timmywillison.com/pres/operators/#landing)".

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a bit shift assignment operator, there is some brief info [here](http://www.tipsntracks.com/341/learning-javascript-tutorial-javascript-expressions-and-operators.html)

Answer (score 0):

Those are bitwise operators. The ">>" practically shifts bits (in binary) to the right.
So you if you have "1010", then applying ">>" operator will return "0101".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

http://www.phpied.com/bitwise-operations-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Shift the bits in color right by "bits" binary digits.